# Group by with count not working Mysql Php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables "employer" and "user", and i want to get total user(according to country) Where "skills" and "entity" column
matches (like query) with both table

Table employer

```
id        skills        entity
1         Php,Design    web
```

Table user

```
id       skills                     entity          country
33       programming,php            web             india
44       Graphic designing,php      design          canada
45       Php                        web             india       
46       Dot net                    test            Sri Lanka
```

Now i want to get result like

```
id      Count       country 
1       2           india
2       1           canada
```

i am trying with following query but not working for me, where i am wrong ?

```
SELECT employer_info.id as employer_id,users_info.country,COUNT(users_info.country) as total 
   FROM employer_info 
   JOIN users_info ON employer_info.skills=users_info.skills 
   GROUP BY users_info.country
```

Comment: Welcome Priya to stackoverflow. You cannot use `employer_info.id`. Remove it and run query again!
Read more for [Group By](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx)

Comment: @x01saa: still not working , showing country:null,total:0

Comment: That's true. There is no common value in skills' column. It seems that you must change your schema (change skills from comma-separated to single skill in each row) or query entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of users in a country by employer, you should count the number of user ids and not the country.

As for the GROUP BY, this should be done on the non-aggregated fields, which are the employer_info.id  and users_info.country

```
SELECT employer_info.id as employer_id,users_info.country,
           COUNT(users_info.id) as total 
       FROM employer_info 
       JOIN users_info 
             ON employer_info.skills=users_info.skills 
       GROUP BY employer_info.id, users_info.country
```

Comment: showing wrong result, showing me following result

employer_id     country   total
1                       null        1
2                       null        1
7                       null        1

Comment: How are you running this query?

Comment: If your employer table contains `Php,Design`, then this must also be the exact same value in the users_info table. It won't match `programming,php` or even `PHP`

Comment: understand but can we use mysql like query with this ? and my second question is if i use same value ( both table value matches ) then also query not working, i tested it properly

Comment: If you want a list of skills, you should be using a separate table, comma separated fields in a relational database isn't a good idea - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`SELECT A.id as employer_id,B.country,COUNT(B.country) as total 
   FROM employer_info A
   JOIN users_info B ON A.skills=B.skills AND A.entity=B.entity
   GROUP BY A.id, B.country`